# firebase.firestore() .set() not firing first time

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not a dev, I'm just learning for my own interest as a hobby.
For my own learning I'm building real world project rather than just following the usual online tutorials.
I'm building a simple vue.js app with vuex and using firebase for auth and db.

I have a method that should just take a value and .set() a new document in a collection with a single piece of data:

HTML

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="testing('1', '2')">Testing</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

SCRIPT

```
methods: {
      testing(id, val) {

          console.log('entered testing:', id, val)

          firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(id)
          .set({
            key: val
          })
          .then(result => {
              console.log('created in firestore', result)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error('failed to create in firestore', error)
          })
        }
...
```

The problem is that **after refreshing the browser** the first time I click the button the method runs.
I see the console log 'entered testing' with the correct id and val but the firestore call doesn't appear to run.
Nothing in the console and no network requests.

The second time I click it I see the .then() console log 'created in firestore: undefined' and what looks like 3 network requests, and the doc and data is set correctly!

Every time I click the button after that I see the correct console log, a single network request and the doc and data is set correctly.

**Other info...**

- I have security rules set up on the db but only basic allow if auth != null
- The user is logged in when I try this.
- I'm not ruling out that there might be something somewhere else in my app which is causing this but there's nothing obvious and I've stripped things right back to debug this. I'm trying to set it up so all firebase requests are done in the store only, with each component just passing it the values it needs, but to debug this I've moved all the logic (including importing firestore) into a single component.

What is going on?
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds like Firebase is/was not initialized properly. Have you followed the setup docs correctly? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I thought so. Why would it not work first click but then work on all clicks after that though?

Comment: Have double checked this and am pretty sure I am initialising firebase correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the tutorial that you are following? Given that the doc and data eventually sets correctly, I don't think there should be anything wrong in the Firebase initialization. My guess is that the issue has to do with the _state management pattern_ that [_Vuex_](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) provides. Perhaps a Firebase misconfiguration with it.

Comment: @DuckinCustard have you found the solution? I'm also facing the same issue in my Application. Firebase stuck in pending state on first button click but works well after second click.